# How do I call a string from another class in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Specifically, SpriteKit.

In GameScene I set the variable:

```
var score = Int()
```

which is constantly being changed. In EndScene.swift, I want to print that score in a label.

What I have for the label usually is:

```
scoreLabel.text = "SCORE:" + String(score)
```

But EndScene doesn't recognize score as a value from GameScene. How can I call 'score' in that string?

In GameScene I have a func called

func updateScore(_ scoreToAdd:Int) {

```
    score = score + scoreToAdd

    scoreLabel.text = "Score: " + String(score)

}
```

That's what score in EndScore should equal. How can I do that?

Comment: Answers below are right, just wanted to mention, writing `var score = Int()` is the same as writing `var score = 0`, and the latter is the best practice way to do it. You shouldn't alloc init an Int like that

Comment: Kayla, I see. Score is being = 0 every time in EndScene. How would you suggest fixing that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that score is defined as public in GameScene.swift so you can access it outside the GameScene class  -

```
public var score = Int()
```

Then make sure that you access it with the GameScene object -

```
let game = GameScene()
scoreLabel.text = "SCORE:" + String(game.score)
```

Comment: I tried that and EndScene recognizes score, but it'll print it as SCORE: 0, regardless of what score really equals in GameScene. I even inserted 
        print(String(score)) in GameScene to make sure score did not = 0. Then in EndScene I inserted print(String(game.score)) and saw the output was 0 every time. What could be going wrong?

Comment: @GabrielsGalaxy Are you making sure that "game" is the same instance as of GameScene.swift and EndScene.swift?

Comment: @GabrielsGalaxy it's probably showing you Score: 0 every time because you are creating a new GameScene object every time you are trying to access the score. You need to hold onto the GameScene object for the life of the app so that all updates to it will be reflected. So EndScene.swift should have a variable that allows you access to the same GameScene object every time you access it as in Daniel Dramond's answer.

Comment: @Joakim yes. I believe it has to do with EndScene taking GameScene initial score value and not the current/ updated on that happens in func updateScore(_ scoreToAdd:Int) {

    score = score + scoreToAdd

    scoreLabel.text = "Score: " + String(score)

}

Comment: @buggy I see. I don't think it's that though. Look at the comment i just wrote^

Comment: As long as your the 'score' var in GameScene is updated, it'll be the updates value when it's accessed. If you are only getting 0 when you access it--even after a call to updateScore(scoreToAdd:) has been made--then that is either proof that every time you are accessing score, it is from a new instance of the GameScene object (thus the initial value of 0 is always returned), or you're accessing the same object every time, but it is different for the object you update elsewhere. I think you need to check again and make sure that you actually have the same GameScene object being referenced.

Comment: @GabrielsGalaxy it would helpful if we knew how you implemented the GameScene object in EndScene.swift. Where is it set and how?

Comment: @Buggy Not sure I completely understand but I am using let game = GameScene(). AND let scene = GameScene(size: self.scene!.size) in my playAgain() func, I'm not sure if that was relevant or not. Also using scoreLabel.text = "SCORE: (game.score)", which is outputting to SCORE: 0

Comment: This will not work, this creates a new game scene object, not the one the user is currently working with

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Agreed, I really think that's what is good by on here, every time she calls out to update the score he's creating a new GameScene and starting over.

Comment: @Buggy well I'm not too sure what you mean by that but the GameScene is displaying the score perfectly, I'm just unable to see it being projected in EndScene

Comment: I agree with Knigh0fDragon in this case you create two GameScene, one parallel to the current ... imagine if your GameScene is big and it use 450kbyte of memory, with this method you have the double occupied..

Answer (score 0):

You should use [NSArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarchiver) to save to a file you value and retrieve it where do you want but it's a long method just to save a single parameter as you wish, so you could save your score value through [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults) (knowed also as Next Step User Defaults or NSDefaults). It's fast and easy to use.

```
// Save score value
UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey:"score")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

// Retrieve score value
if let savedScore = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "score") {
    print(savedScore)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are moving to your EndScene,  use the `userData` to transfer data.

```
func movingToEndScene()
{
    let endScene = EndScene(...)
    let userData = ["score":score]
    endScene.userData = userData
    self.view.presentScene(endScene)
}
```

Then, inside your end scene, you can do whatever you want with it:

```
scoreLabel.text = "\(self.userData["score"])"
```